# jasmine-node not going inside it block

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

> ```
> var jasmine = require('jasmine-node');
>
> describe('Report Comparison ', function () {
>
>     it('test case', function () {
>         console.log('Inside It');
>         expect("1").toBe(1);
>     });
> });
> ```

I have this simple testcase for trial.
But while execution the code inside `it` block is not executed.

Comment: How you execute tests? Have you read https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node#usage

Comment: Im running the js file from terminal.
> "node test.js". 
Also from Webstorm IDE by directly running the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to install jasmine-node globally.

```
npm install -g jasmine-node
```

You don't need to require `jasmine-node` in your test file. Just run your test like this instead of `node test.js`:

```
jasmine-node spec/SampleSpec.js  // For a single file

jasmine-node spec/  // For running multiple specs inside the `spec/` directory
```

Straight from the [docs](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node#usage),

**Note:** your specification files must be named as `spec.js`, `spec.coffee` or `spec.litcoffee`, which matches the regular expression `/spec\.(js|coffee|litcoffee)$/i`; otherwise jasmine-node won't find them! For example, `sampleSpecs.js` is wrong, `sampleSpec.js` is right.